# A sufficient condition for two semigroups to be norm equivalent?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, semigroups-of-operators

Consider two densely defined, strictly positive, self-adjoint operators $A$ and $B$ with the following property
$$\|A^k x\| \simeq \|B^k x\|, \quad\forall x \in D(A^k)= D(B^k),$$
for $k=1,2,\cdots, M$, where $M$ can be $\infty$.

Do we have for fixed $t>0$,
$$\|T(t) x \| \simeq \|S(t) x\|, $$
where $T(t),S(t)$ are the semigroups generated by $A,B$?

Does it hold only when $M = \infty$?
Or does it hold under some extra assumptions?

Notation: $a \simeq b$ means there exist a positive constant $C$ such that $\frac{1}{C}a \leq b \leq C a.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition $\|A^k x\| \simeq \|B^k x\|$ can be rewritten, by squaring both sides, as $\langle x, A^{2k} x \rangle \simeq \langle x, B^{2k} x \rangle$, i.e. $A^{2k} \leqslant C B^{2k}$ and $B^{2k} \leqslant C A^{2k}$. Recall now that the function $s \mapsto s^{\alpha}$ is operator monotone for $\alpha \in (0,1]$. It means that if you fix $t$, then you should take any $k \geqslant t$ and consider the function $s \mapsto s^{\frac{t}{k}}$, to conclude that $A^{2t} \leqslant C^{\frac{t}{k}} B^{2t}$ and $ B^{2t} \leqslant C^{\frac{t}{k}} A^{2t}$, from which it follows that $\|T(t)x\|\simeq \|S(t) x\|$. In this answer I assumed that in this setting by semigroups $T(t)$ and $S(t)$ you meant $A^{t}$ and $B^{t}$.

EDIT: It also holds for $T(t)=\exp(tA)$ and $S(t)=\exp(tB)$. First of all, note that by our norm condition the sets of analytic vectors for $A$ and $B$ are the same, so we can work on this common analytic domain and disregard all the issues coming from unboudedness. If $x$ is analytic then $\|T(t)x\|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2t)^{k}}{k!} \langle x, A^{k} x\rangle$ and $\|S(t)x\|^2 = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(2t)^{k}}{k!} \langle x, B^{k} x\rangle$, so the same computation as in the first version gives $\|S(t)x\| \simeq \|T(t)x\|$.

EDIT #2: It turns out that if there exists a constant $C$ such that $\frac{1}{C} \|A^{k} x\| \leqslant \|B^{k} x\| \leqslant C \|A^{k}x\|$ and $D(A^k)=D(B^k)$ for any $k$ then $A=B$. As remarked above, both operators have the same analytics vectors and they form a core, so it suffices to work with them. We can therefore write $\frac{1}{C} \langle x, A^{2k} x\rangle \leqslant \langle x, B^{2k} x\rangle \leqslant C \langle x, A^{2k} \rangle$, i.e. $\frac{1}{C} A^{2k} \leqslant B^{2k} \leqslant C A^{2k}$. Since the function $s \mapsto s^{\frac{1}{2k}}$ is operator monotone, we get $\frac{1}{C^{\frac{1}{2k}}} A \leqslant B \leqslant C^{\frac{1}{2k}} A$, i.e. $\frac{1}{C^{\frac{1}{2k}}}\langle x, A x\rangle \leqslant \langle x, Bx\rangle \leqslant C^{\frac{1}{2k}}\langle x, Ax\rangle$ for any analytic vector $x$. Note that the proof of operator monotonicity of $s \mapsto s^{\frac{1}{2k}}$ follows from an appropriate integral representation of this function, so our analyticity assumption shows that we can perform it in our situation. Letting $k\to \infty$ we get $\langle x, Ax\rangle= \langle x, Bx\rangle$ for any analytic vector $x$. By polarisation and density of analytic vectors we may conclude that $Ax=Bx$ for any analytic vector and therefore $A=B$, since the analytic domain forms a core.

Comment: I think that the semigroups are rather meant to be $\exp(tA)$, i.e.\ $A$ and $B$ are the *infinitesimal* generators.

Comment: @JochenWengenroth:  It may well be the case, so I also added the proof in this case. First I assumed the other version because of the positivity assumption on $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.In the exponential case, do we require $M = \infty$? Since we are taking infinite sum.

Comment: @newbie: Yes, I think so.

Comment: What if there are only few analytic vectors?

Comment: @AndrásBátkai: the operators are self-adjoint, so the analytic vectors form a core for the domains. Actually, I realised that the assumptions force $A=B$, so I'll edit the answer.

Comment: It just came to my mind, could it be the case if one of the operators is not selfadjoint? Say we take two strongly elliptic differential operators, one is selfadjoint while the other is not. I have a hunch it should be the case as elliptic operators are usually compared with Laplacian, but I only know little about this field. To clarify, I am looking a situation that $A\neq B$ but the equivalence of semigroups still holds.